# Core Data: Instantiating a "root object" in a document based application

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsobjectcontroller

I am creating a document based project using Core Data and have run into what may simply be a conceptual issue for me, as while I am not new to Cocoa, this is my first attempt to utilize Core Data.  What I am trying to accomplish should be relatively simple:  with each new document launched, I would like a new instance of one of my model objects created that serves as a "root" object.

What I have done is add an NSObjectController to my xib, set its mode to Entity Name (with the correct entity name provided), checked off "Prepares Content", and bound its managed object context to File's Owner with managedObjectContext as the model key path.  To test this, I bound the title of my main window to the object controller, with controller key as selection and model key path as one of the keys in my entity.

I know I can create my root object programmatically, but am trying to adopt the mediator pattern as is recommended by Apple.  I have seen the instructions in the department-employee tutorial under the "adopting the mediator pattern" section and the steps detailed are exactly what I believe I have done.

Any thoughts?

Edit:
Perhaps I did not state the problem correctly.  The models are created in Core Data and the relationships are setup as I need them to be (with a "root", children and leaves, using to-one parent relationships, to-many children relationships and an isLeaf boolean attribute).  My issue is ensuring that this root object is instantiated as a singleton every time a new document is launched.  There should be exactly a 1:1 relationship between the root object and the current document, that root object must always exist and be available without any user interaction to create it, and child nodes that are created and attached to the root are the data objects that are used and manipulated by the application.

I have implemented the above functionality programatically, but in keeping with Core Data principles, would like to adopt the mediator pattern completely and not manage any creation of data objects within my application logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "root" managed object like you would find in linked-list or tree, then you have to set that up in data model itself.

By default, a Core Data data model has no particular hierarchy among objects. Objects may be related but no object is logically "above" or "below" another one. You can reach in object in any relationship by starting with any other object and walking the relationship/s back to the desired object.

A hierarchy of managed objects needs a tree like structure like this:

```
Tree{
    nodeName:string
    parent<-->>Tree.children
    children<<-->Tree.parent
}
```

... so that the "root" object is the sole `Tree` instances that has `parent==nil`.

Having said all this, I would point out that the Apple docs you refer to say that it is best ***NOT*** to use this type of built in hierarchy for most cases. It's just a simplification used for purposes of demonstration (and I think it is a bad one.)

The data model is intended to model/simulate the real-world objects, conditions or events that the app deals with. As such, the logical relationships between the entities/objects in the model/graph should reflect the real-world relationships. In this case, unless the real-world things you are modeling exist in a hierarchy with a real-world "root" object, condition or event, then your model shouldn't have one either.

Comment: Actually the tree hierarchy does reflect the real-world model that would be applicable to this particular project.

Comment: If it fits, its fits, I just wanted to caution you not use a tree structure just because is shows up in the examples or might be used in another API.